# Applying a probabilistic function over specific element of an array individually with Numpy/Python

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I'm fairly new to Python/Numpy. What I have here is a standard array and I have a function which I have vectorized appropriately.

```
def f(i):
     return np.random.choice(2,1,p=[0.7,0.3])*9
f = np.vectorize(f)
```

Defining an example array:

```
array = np.array([[1,1,0],[0,1,0],[0,0,1]])
```

With the vectorized function, f, I would like to evaluate f on each cell on the array with a value of 0.

I am trying to leave for loops as a last resort. My arrays will eventually be larger than 100 by 100, so running each cell individually to look and evaluate f might take too long.

I have tried:

```
print f(array[array==0])
```

Unfortunately, this gives me a row array consisting of 5 elements (the zeroes in my original array).

Alternatively I have tried,

```
array[array==0] = f(1)
```

But as expected, this just turns every single zero element of array into 0's or 9's.

What I'm looking for is somehow to give me my original array with the zero elements replaced individually. Ideally, 30% of my original zero elements will become 9 and the array structure is conserved.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason your first try doesn't work is because the vectorized function handle, let's call it `f_v` to distinguish it from the original `f`, is performing the operation **for** exactly 5 elements: the 5 elements that are returned by the boolean indexing operation `array[array==0]`. That *returns* 5 values, it doesn't *set* those 5 items to the returned values. Your analysis of why the 2nd form fails is spot-on.

If you wanted to solve it you could combine your second approach with adding the `size` option to `np.random.choice`:

```
array = np.array([[1,1,0],[0,1,0],[0,0,1]])
mask = array==0
array[mask] = np.random.choice([18,9], size=mask.sum(), p=[0.7, 0.3])
# example output:
# array([[ 1,  1,  9],
#        [18,  1,  9],
#        [ 9, 18,  1]])
```

There was no need for `np.vectorize`: the `size` option takes care of that already.

Comment: This is the perfect solution! I'm a little confused about what the size option exactly entails.

I have just run this through python and the mask returns an array consisting of boolean indices, and the combination of code `mask.sum()` returns the total number of Trues present in the array.

Comment: Sorry, there appears to be a 5 minute time frame for edits:

How exactly does the size option work to layer over the generated numbers over the masked original array?

Comment: @kevenren, so the `size` parameter of `np.random.choice` simply tells you how many random elements should be generated and what the resultant output array's shape would be. So `np.random.choice([1,2,3], size=(3,4))` would generate a 2D array with 3 rows, 4 columns and each value would be one of either `1`, `2` or `3` (here with equal probability). Because I'm passing simply an integer (`mask.sum()` gives the number of zeroes insize the array `array`), it will return a 1D array with that many elements needed to "overlay" all the zero values.